# NSTableView Doesn't work when in ViewController

Tags: swift, macos

For some reason when I put my code for my `NSTableView` in a `ViewController`, none of the cells appear, but if I put the code in the `AppDelegate`, everything works great.

Any ideas as to why this is happening? I'm working with a .xib file if that helps at all.

```
class ViewController: NSViewController{
    var delegate: AppDelegate? = nil

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        delegate = NSApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }
}

extension ViewController: NSTableViewDataSource{    
    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        print(delegate?.FlightList.count ?? 0)
        return delegate?.FlightList.count ?? 0
    }
}

extension ViewController: NSTableViewDelegate{
    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {

        var text: String = ""
        var cellIdentifier: String = ""


        guard let item = delegate?.FlightList[row] else {
            return nil
        }


        if tableColumn == tableView.tableColumns[0] {
            text = item.flightName
            cellIdentifier = "flightID"
        }

        if let cell = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(cellIdentifier), owner: nil) as? NSTableCellView {
            cell.textField?.stringValue = text
            return cell
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: Without seeing any code it is almost impossible to say.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Ok, I added my code for my ViewController. Should I also add the delegate code?

Comment: As a general rule I think you should avoid having your data source (`FlightList`) or any similar application data in your `AppDelegate` class.

Comment: Which object is the delegate and datasource of the table view in the xib?

Comment: How do you instantiate the view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to implement the **NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate** protocols to tell the table this is the class its getting data from else the

```
 tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.delegate = self
```

wont work and then you wont need to use the app delegate